# Where do I get Visual Studio for Android?

Tags: android, visual-studio

I have heard that I can develop Android apps in Visual Studio. I have VS for Windows apps. How/where do I get VS for Android apps?
Or is it some add-on for the VS for Windows apps itself?
I got Xamarin Studio. But it doesn't seem to have the drag-and-drop feature.

Comment: This is not quite a programming question. Google helps.

Comment: I doubt it's worth the money to get the paid versions of xamarin just for a drag and drop feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy a paid copy of Mono for Android from [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/). Business version and up allows you to develop directly using C# in Visual Studio. The free version offers Xamarin Studio instead.

Disclaimer: I am not related to Xamarin

Comment: Xamarin Studio is a great IDE in it's own right. I'd rate it as one of the best I've used.